# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,131,111'

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to implement a function that takes in a filename and a list of column names and returns a list of integers that contains the values in those columns from every row. Below is my code

```
def extract_election_votes(filename, column_names):

    election = open(filename, encoding="iso-8859-1")
    input_file = csv.DictReader(election)
    results = []
    # store vote counts
    for row in input_file:
        for col in column_names:
            x = row[col].replace(",", "")
            x = row[col].replace("", '')
            # replacing commas/quotes w empty string
            if row[col] == " ":
                continue
            # ignores cells w no data
            votes = int(x)
            # convert string to integer
            results.append(votes)
    election.close()
    return results
```

I am getting an error with the line `votes = int(x)` that says `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,131,111'`. How can I fix my code so that this error does not persist?

Here is my assertion:

```
ir_data = extract_election_votes("election-iran-2009.csv", ["Ahmadinejad", "Rezai", "Karrubi", "Mousavi"])
```

Here is the data for reference:
[ElectionDataFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIClr.png)

Thanks!

Comment: `int(x.replace(",",""))`

Comment: What is `x = row[col].replace("", '')` supposed to do? It's a no-op, and it's overwriting `x` after you've removed the commas.

Comment: i see, so i should remove it

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the old value of x with the second replace, so the commas come back. The second replace should be `x.replace(...)` instead of `row[col].replace(...)`.

Comment: so like this? ```for row in input_file:
        for col in column_names: x = row[col].replace(",", "") x = x.replace("", '')```

Comment: ^ if so, this is the error that displays: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '```